# Microsoft to cease support for Vista, any options for a laptop just purchased?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

According to an article today in [The Register](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/04/13/microsoft_windows_vista_end_of_life_support/), Microsoft will no longer support Vista from the end of this month.

I have a laptop that is not even a year old using an operating system that will not even have had a year's support and I've heard that upgrading to Windows 7 is nearly impossible.

What are my options?

Comment: If your laptop is less than a year old with Vista, it is eligible for a free migration to Windows 7. Also, rework your question to focus on an actual objective fact, and not the "is anyone else angry".

Comment: I'm sorry, very few questions about Microsoft products have real answers: leaving only one response - anger.. that and banging your head against a brick wall. Want to know something about Linux? There's an answer. Want to do something using a Microsoft product? Don't make us laugh.

Comment: @PP - start a blog. This kind of thoughts belongs there, not on Super User.

Comment: Support for Vista with whatever the latest SP is will probably end sometime in 2013 or later.

Comment: "I've heard that upgrading to Windows 7 is nearly impossible." - Where have you heard this??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read the article again - MS are not dropping support for Vista, only for non-service packed Vista.

> The company announced in February that the ***service pack-free version*** of its post-XP, pre-Windows 7 OS would hit end of life support in April.

My emphasis.

As long as you are running SP2 you will still be covered.

Comment: Ah; this is reasonable. Thank you for making that clear.